# Shouldn't typescript show a compile error for using the $ object without an import line for jQuery?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

This is my app.ts

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("hello world");
});
```

It will show compile error:

```
[ts] Cannot find name '$'.
```

This error disappears when I run:

```
npm install --save @types/jquery
```

My understanding above command is purely for intellisense purpose to help with auto completing. So I am still expecting Typescript or Visual Studio Code to show me compile errors on not knowing what $ object is.

This is how my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "ts-definition-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.40"
  }
}
```

This is how my project setup looks like
[image: This is how my project setup looks like]

Question: Why do I not get any compile errors for "$" even though am not importing jquery like this: `import * as $ from "jquery";`

Comment: probably because the jquery definition files adds $ to the window interface as well (as it actually happens at runtime).

Comment: So no need for `import * as $ from "jquery";`. This feels wrong.

Comment: why would you import something that is already present in the global context? what would be the point of importing it?

Comment: You said in first comment that "the jquery definition files adds $ to the window interface as well". Isn't this bad????? Adding stuff to global window? I can't find anything on Typescript site to verify this comment. Any links would be appreciated.

Comment: It is arguably a bad practice, but it is in fact what jquery does. The definition just expresses that fact.

Comment: That's what JQuery does because JQuery is an old library that came way before modules even existed. This is not particular of TypeScript or even JavaScript. It's what JQuery does. Therefore it's what the type definition does.